# Simulation runs only for smaller number of iterations

Tags: probability-or-statistics

> The following code does not run for larger number of iterations . It runs for n=5 ,10 etc. but does not run for n=50 or greater. I tried to limit the accuracy goal and precision goal in 'FindDistributionParameters'. Any suggestions? Wondering at what place should I try ?NumericQ !

```
ClearAll[a0, d0]
ZP[sigma_, alpha_, theta_] := 
ProbabilityDistribution[alpha theta/
sigma (1 - Exp[-(x/sigma)^alpha])^(theta - 1) Exp[-(x/sigma)^
alpha ]*(x/sigma)^(alpha - 1), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
Assumptions -> sigma > 0 && alpha > 0 && theta > 0];
DistributionParameterAssumptions[ZP[sigma, alpha, theta]];
mydata = 
Sort[RandomVariate[ZP[15, 2, 4], 50]]; myLCData = Take[mydata, -40];
Table[myinitalParameters = 
Values[FindDistributionParameters[mydata, ZP[a0, 2, d0]]] // 
FullSimplify; 
myTData := Sort[RandomVariate[TruncatedDistribution[{0,Min[myLCData]}, 
ZP[myinitalParameters[[1]], 2, myinitalParameters[[2]]]], 10]]; 
myPCData := Join[myLCData, myTData]; mydata = myPCData;
myinitalParameters, {i, 5}]
```

Comment: Your code runs fine on my computer with `{i, 50}` at the end. Try wrapping your `Table` in a [`Monitor[..., i]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Monitor.html) command to see how it's progressing.

Comment: It is not working on my computer. Adding monitor is not much help. Can you run it for i=100? Thanks.

Comment: For `{i, 100}` this code takes 86 seconds on my laptop, running Mathematica 12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019). What is your `$Version`?

Comment: My version is 11.3.0. on McBook Air. I am still struggling with n=50.

Comment: Try with a fresh kernel? A MacBook Air isn't exactly powerful, but still it should do.